# What is "convertView" parameter in ArrayAdapter getView() method

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me what the `convertView` parameter is used for in the `getView()` method of the `Adapter` class?

Here is a sample code take from [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    Order o = items.get(position);
    if (o != null) {
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        if (tt != null) {
            tt.setText("Name: "+o.getOrderName());                            }
        if(bt != null){
            bt.setText("Status: "+ o.getOrderStatus());
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

What should we pass via `convertView`?

What I've found, [take from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html):

> Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the
>   data set. You can either create a View manually or inflate it from an
>   XML layout file. When the View is inflated, the parent View (GridView,
>   ListView...) will apply default layout parameters unless you use
>   inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) to specify a root view
>   and to prevent attachment to the root.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *position* -- The position of the item within the adapter's data set of the item whose  view we want.
>
> *convertView* -- The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before
>   using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the
>   correct data, this method can create a new view.
>
> *parent* -- The parent that this view will eventually be attached to Returns
>
> *returns* -- A View corresponding to the data at the specified position.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling that method by yourself.

Android's `ListView` uses an `Adapter` to fill itself with `Views`. When the `ListView` is shown, it starts calling `getView()` to populate itself. When the user scrolls a new view should be created, so for performance the `ListView` sends the `Adapter` an old view that it's not used any more in the `convertView` param.

Comment: I didn't quite understand this "When the user scrolls a new view should be created, so for performance the ListView sends the Adapter an old view that it's not used any more in the convertView param." You say `ListView` doens't populate all the views at once?

Comment: @Braveyard: Nope. Imagine the `ListView` will hold 1.000 items. It can't load everything to memory and it just use the minimum amount to show in the screen.

Comment: A significant side effect to this is that storing any state information in the Views for a ListView is bound to be a disaster.  Make sure you store any per-item state in the Adapter, not in the Views.

Comment: @jib: Or you can just handle the views changing state correctly.