# What is the purpose of `convertView` in ListView adapter?

Tags: java, android

In android, I usually use `MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter` to create view for the `ListView`, and as a result, I have to override the function

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // somecode here
}
```

However, i don't know exactly what `convertView` and `parent` do! Does anyone have a suggestion? More detail, more help! Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the documentation,

> convertView - The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view.

In other words, this parameter is used strictly to increase the performance of your `Adapter`. When a `ListView` uses an `Adapter` to fill its rows with `View`s, the adapter populates each list item with a `View` object by calling `getView()` on each row. The Adapter uses the `convertView` as a way of recycling old `View` objects that are no longer being used. In this way, the `ListView` can send the Adapter old, "recycled" view objects that are no longer being displayed instead of instantiating an entirely new object each time the Adapter wants to display a new list item. This is the purpose of the `convertView` parameter.

Answer (score 31):

`convertView` is used to reuse old view.

Please understand `Adapter` [functionality](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) in android. `Adapter` enables you to reuse some view with new data.

So if a list is of 15 items, but window can show only 5 items, then at first `convertView` would be null, and we need to create new views for these five items, but when you scroll down, you have two options, either create 6-10 views, or re-use old views and load new data into these views.
`Adapter` and `convertView` enables you to do the later method.

Comment: Very useful. Described in simple words.

Answer (score 6):

convertView is the ListView Item Cache that is not visible, and hence it can be reused. It lets the ListView need not create a lot of ListItems, hence saving memeory and making the ListView more smooth.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = this.inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }
    else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    // remaining implementation
    return view;
}
```

Comment: So, should I use convertView if I build my view without inflating a XML file ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel yes, you do

Answer (score 3):

**Shorter Version** :

Please read @Alex Lockwood's and @jeet's answer.

**My Answer** :

Before why, which is the *better/proper* way of using `convertView` in `getView()`? Well explained by Romain Guy in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA).

An **example**,

```
@Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)            {
   View rowView = convertView;
   ViewHolder holderObject;

 if (rowView == null) {
     rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_post_or_comment, parent, false);
     holderObject = new HolderForContent();
     mapHolder(holderObject, rowView);
     rowView.setTag(holderObject);
   } else {
     holderObject = (HolderForContent) convertView.getTag();
   }
   setHolderValues(holderObject, position);
   return rowView;
 }
 
 private class ViewHolder {
    TextView mTextView;
 }
 
 mapHolder(holderObject, rowView) {
    //assume R.id.mTextView exists
    holderObject.mTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
 }
 
 setHolderValues(holderObject, position) {
    //assume this arrayList exists
    String mString = arrayList.get(position).mTextViewContent;
    holderObject.mTextView.setText(mString);
 }
```

Above is just an example, you can follow any type of pattern. But **remember this**,

```
@Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 
   if (convertView == null) {
        // todo : inflate rowView. Map view in xml.
   } else {
        // todo : get already defined view references
   }

   // todo : set data to display
 
 return rowView;
 
 }
```

Now coming to **purpose** of `convertView`. The *why*?

`convertView` is used for **performance optimization** [[see](https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_0230_TurboChargeYourUI-HowtomakeyourAndroidUIfastandefficient.pdf) chart in slide 14 by Romain Guy] by not recreating view that was created already.

**Sources** :
Any corrections are welcome. I actually gathered this info through these links,

Read about `getView()` in Android developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)).

Romain Guy speaking about `getView()` in [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) "Turbo Charge Your UI" at Google IO 2009 and [material](https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_0230_TurboChargeYourUI-HowtomakeyourAndroidUIfastandefficient.pdf) used for presentation.

A wonderful [blog](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) by Lucas Rocha.

Those who want to take a deep dive into source code : [ListView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/dcce1216b0066f3f9ed1b01a485684e8617e7ea4/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java) and a sample [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#369) of `getView()` can be seen in source code for arrayAdapter.

**Similar SO posts.**

[what-is-convertview-parameter-in-arrayadapter-getview-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382176/what-is-convertview-parameter-in-arrayadapter-getview-method)

[how-do-i-choose-convertview-to-reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099455/how-do-i-choose-convertview-to-reuse)

[how-does-the-getview-method-work-when-creating-your-own-custom-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120119/how-does-the-getview-method-work-when-creating-your-own-custom-adapter)