# should I always use convertView as my main ViewElement in Base adapter?

Tags: android, baseadapter, getview, convertview

the variable convertView in getView of BaseAdapter . What is it for? when creating items should I always use convertView? What is the problem if I don't use it?

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560624/what-is-the-purpose-of-convertview-in-listview-adapter

Comment: that helped . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What is it for?
```

it an instance of the `View` if you inflate, the first time its value is null. E.g.

```
 if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflate...
 }
```

> when creating items should I always use convertView?

yes, but try to implement the ViewHolder pattern around it. It will speed up the scroll's performance.

> What is the problem if I don't use it?

it depends on the the number of items you have in your `ListView`. We can go from laggy ux to crashes.