# Android - Native ad refreshes everytime it comes to focus

Tags: android, listview, admob, native-ads

I have implemented a native ad in my ListView, it works fine but reloads every time it comes to focus. Is there any way I can hold the instance or the view so it doesn't reload every time. Or can I block the recreation of the view?

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String content, currentFile, pv;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fileList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {



        if (i == 0) {

            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

            // ad loads here

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.native_ad_item, null);
                final CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) view.findViewById(R.id.nativeAd);
                AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("264647BDFDDB6FBB0F34C797D5D53A4D").build();
                adView.loadAd(request);



            }

        } else {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchased_list_item, null);

            // rest of the code

        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView reuses the child views created in getView() and sends them as the second parameter (which is actually called **convertView**) of that method. You can check if that View is not null and use it instead of creating a new one each time.
You can see more details in the answers to this question:
[What is the purpose of `convertView` in ListView adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560624/what-is-the-purpose-of-convertview-in-listview-adapter)