# Android ListView adding too many items

Tags: android, for-loop, android-listview, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I am currently adding TextViews inside a LinearLayout inside a ListView element using a for loop, because the amount of TextViews I have to add in there is variable. I am adding the items to the ListViews like you normally do.
The problem is, when I scroll the items start to get more and more and when I scroll back up I end up with hundreds of items. I think it is because the ListView is reloading and cycling through the for loop once again and so adding every TextView multiple times. Can I stop that?

My code:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    private final Context context;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context,  R.layout.list, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_line);
            holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_linear);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

            String data = rowItem.getData();
            String[] split0 = data.split("=");

            Log.e("DATA", data);
            Log.e("LINE", rowItem.getTitle());

            for (int j = 0; j < split0.length; j++) {
                String[] split1 = split0[j].split(":");

                LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.context);
                parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                for (int k = 0; k < split1.length; k++) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.context);
                    textView.setText(split1[k]);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    textView.setTextSize(18);

                    parentLayout.addView(textView);
                }
                holder.linearLayout.addView(parentLayout);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My data sceme looks like this for one entry:

```
text1:text2=text3:text4
```

How it will look on the list:

```
text1    text2
text3    text4
```

Comment: use standard viewHolder model and remove allViews of LinearLayout first before running ur view addition code using viewGroup.removeAllViews()

Comment: could you give me any code example of how I would do that?

Comment: post your code.It would be more helpful to give suggestion.

Comment: Try moving your loops inside the `if (convertView == null)` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the ArrayAdapter will call `getView()` each time the row becomes visible.  If the row has been set up previously, it will pass in the previously set up View in the `convertView` parameter.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382176/what-is-convertview-parameter-in-arrayadapter-getview-method) for details.  From [the documentation](http://The%20old%20view%20to%20reuse,%20if%20possible.%20Note:%20You%20should%20check%20that%20this%20view%20is%20non-null%20and%20of%20an%20appropriate%20type%20before%20using.%20If%20it%20is%20not%20possible%20to%20convert%20this%20view%20to%20display%20the%20correct%20data,%20this%20method%20can%20create%20a%20new%20view.%20Heterogeneous%20lists%20can%20specify%20their%20number%20of%20view%20types,%20so%20that%20this%20View%20is%20always%20of%20the%20right%20type%20(see%20getViewTypeCount()%20and%20getItemViewType(int)).) for `convertView`:

> The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this
>   view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not
>   possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method
>   can create a new view. Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of
>   view types, so that this View is always of the right type (see
>   getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int)).

Edit:  Since the original code proposed was causing problems, it looks like you might not be able to use the standard view holder design pattern after all.  You have a unique set-up, where you are creating a dynamic amount of items in each row.

You might be able to do something that is slightly optimized, where you don't have to call `inflate()` on each `getView()` call, but still re-create the `ViewHolder` each time `getView()` is called, in order to populate the correct data when scrolling:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_list, null);

    } 

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_line);
    holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_linear);
    convertView.setTag(holder);


    holder.title.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        String data = rowItem.getData();
        String[] split0 = data.split("=");

        Log.e("DATA", data);
        Log.e("LINE", rowItem.getTitle());

        for (int j = 0; j < split0.length; j++) {
            String[] split1 = split0[j].split(":");

            LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.context);
            parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (int k = 0; k < split1.length; k++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.context);
                textView.setText(split1[k]);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                textView.setTextSize(18);

                parentLayout.addView(textView);
            }
            holder.linearLayout.addView(parentLayout);
        }


    return convertView;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could just go back to the basics, and just completely re-create the view on each call to `getView()`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_line);
            holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_linear);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.title.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

            String data = rowItem.getData();
            String[] split0 = data.split("=");

            Log.e("DATA", data);
            Log.e("LINE", rowItem.getTitle());

            for (int j = 0; j < split0.length; j++) {
                String[] split1 = split0[j].split(":");

                LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.context);
                parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                for (int k = 0; k < split1.length; k++) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.context);
                    textView.setText(split1[k]);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    textView.setTextSize(18);

                    parentLayout.addView(textView);
                }
                holder.linearLayout.addView(parentLayout);
            }     

        //} 

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: So now I have the problem that it doesn't take all my data to display. Let's say I have 10 entries to display in the listview, it only takes the data of the first 4 and displays it over and over again, till all 10 entries are displayed. The titles get displayed normally though. Basically it displays the first 4 entries over and over again, instead of one of each of the 10

Comment: @Broadwell That's strange.  It sounds like it might problem with your data source, whatever you pass into `List<RowItem> items` in this adapter.  Try verifying that the List contains what you expect.  If you can't get it sorted out post a new question and I'll take a look!

Comment: I double checked the data and it contains everything I want. I also noticed convertView is no longer null after the first 4 lists. Anyway, here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410333/android-listview-only-using-first-entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78604/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-broadwell).

Comment: Yeah ok. How to do that?

Comment: Oh you added a link. derp